# With two overlapping canvases, can I pass mouse events to the bottom one?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to draw some guide lines via `fabric.js` like the [online editor app on printio.ru](http://printio.ru/canvases20x30/new?quantity=1&frame_type=no_frame).

So far, I placed 2 canvases with the same size in one page, the top one is to be a static workcanvas which used to draw some guide lines and the bottom canvas will contain some interactive objects.  This seems to be how they do it in the page on the link above.

However, I can't work with those objects on the bottom canvas because the top canvas interrupts mouse events.  Is there a way to let the mouse events to pass through to the bottom canvas?  I am thinking of something like `canvas.mouseenabled=false` on the top canvas - is that possible?

I have thought of an alternative solution: place the guide lines and other objects in one single canvas.  I don't like that solution because it adds things that I don't want to the bottom canvas and, in that case, I have to add some line instances instead of just draw line by context2d, which I think will give me low performance

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow!  Your question came to me in a queue to help improve its readability and so help it to get more answers.  I have re-worded it a little - including adding a link to the app that I think you want to replicate.  Can you check the edits and make sure it still asks what you want?  It wasn't totally clear before.  I've also formatted code with ` characters around the.  Finally edited the title to be more specific and hopefully attract more experts in this field. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Apply css-property
`pointer-events:none`
to upper elements, mouse events can through.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

It will be work for modern browser.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events